# Add a view to a listView and to a scrollView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I try to add a View to a ScrollView AND to a Layout (Linear or Relative doesn't change anything) in the same controller

```
RelativeLayout header = (RelativeLayout)((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.frame_header, null);
mListView.addHeaderView(header);
mLayout.addView(header);
```

But when i do that, it crash with

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

Moreover, when i only assign my view to the listView OR to the Layout it works perfectly..

Anyone has an idea to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `View` can only have one parent, so what you want is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, so i've to create another view and assign to it all i've assigned to the other one?

Comment: @ClémentBouly: You cannot add the same `View` to two parents. How you work around that (two separate `Views`, only add the `View` to one parent and get rid of the other one) is up to you.